Can't fetch a simple API in WidgetKit
I can't fetch a simple API in WidgetKit. I want to fetch data in a widget from an API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1. It doesn't work. I tried it in Swift apps, JavaScript, and cURL, and it works perfectly everywhere except in the WidgetKit environment. I can't fetch a simple API in WidgetKit. Specifically, I want to retrieve data from the API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1. However, it doesn’t work in the widget.
Here's my code:
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Post: Decodable {
    let title: String
}

struct Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), title: "Loading...", configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent())
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), title: "Preview Title", configuration: configuration)
    }

    func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<SimpleEntry> {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        let currentDate = Date()
        
        let title = await fetchPostTitle() ?? "Failed to load title"

        for hourOffset in 0..<5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, title: title, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        return Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    }

    private func fetchPostTitle() async -> String? {
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")!
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let post = try JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data)
            return post.title
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching post: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let title: String
    let configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent
}

struct PostWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Post Title:")
            Text(entry.title)
                .font(.headline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            Text("Time:")
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)
                .font(.footnote)
        }
    }
}

struct PostWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "PostWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationAppIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            PostWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .containerBackground(.fill.tertiary, for: .widget)
        }
    }
}

Here are the errors I get:
networkd_settings_read_from_file Sandbox is preventing this process from reading networkd settings file at "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkd.plist", please add an exception.
The sandbox profile for this process is preventing communication with network content filters. Please modify the sandbox profile to allow access to the com.apple.nesessionmanager.content-filter Mach service
nw_resolver_can_use_dns_xpc_block_invoke Sandbox does not allow access to com.apple.dnssd.service
nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C1.1] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
Connection 1: received failure notification
Connection 1: failed to connect 10:-72000, reason -1
Connection 1: encountered error(10:-72000)
Task <32EC2820-3C35-4D72-BDD6-541D73FFE25E>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [10:-72000])
Task <32EC2820-3C35-4D72-BDD6-541D73FFE25E>.<1> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSUnderlyingError=0x12f606760 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, _NSURLErrorNWResolutionReportKey=Resolved 0 endpoints in 1ms using unknown from query, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns, uses wifi}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <32EC2820-3C35-4D72-BDD6-541D73FFE25E>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <32EC2820-3C35-4D72-BDD6-541D73FFE25E>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}
nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C2.1] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
Connection 2: received failure notification
Connection 2: failed to connect 10:-72000, reason -1
Connection 2: encountered error(10:-72000)
Task <69DF6341-40DA-4519-B132-F827D665243F>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [10:-72000])
Task <69DF6341-40DA-4519-B132-F827D665243F>.<2> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSUnderlyingError=0x140822a20 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, _NSURLErrorNWResolutionReportKey=Resolved 0 endpoints in 0ms using unknown from query, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns, uses wifi}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <69DF6341-40DA-4519-B132-F827D665243F>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDownloadTask <69DF6341-40DA-4519-B132-F827D665243F>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}
[S:1] Error received: Connection invalidated.

Tried in Swift apps, JavaScript, and cURL – works everywhere except in the widget.
